# Check for window.open support - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari, window

I am working on fixing a bug regarding `window.open` being triggered on mobile safari. Whenever this happens, an error is triggered as it seems `window` is not defined or the function is not supported?

The approach I am considering taking is to check if `window.open` is supported. If so, open the window like normal. If not, simply redirect the page. But how could I check for this support?

```
if (window.open) {
   var helpWindow = window.open('help.htm', 'DBHelp', 'width=800,height=600,left=100,top=100');
} else {
   this.navigateTo('help.htm');
}
```

This is what I am trying, only with some dummy data in the URL for now. How could I best go about this?

Comment: What is the exact error message? I've never seen alternatives in JS error messages.

Comment: helpWindow is undefined.

Comment: That message comes outside of the code you've posted. Anyway, a pop-up blocker have done its job, or you're trying to use `helpWindow` afterwards, and `window.open` is not supported. You can check if `helpWindow` exists in the if block, after `window.open(...)`, if it doesn't, provide an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.open to open a random page and check for the body element. If it's there, then the page opened correctly, so window.open is supported.

Edit: Even better, window.open will return null if the call failed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `window.open` is defined, but it's not able to open a new window. So check the return value rather than the function name.

```
var helpWindow = window.open('help.htm', 'DBHelp', 'width=800,height=600,left=100,top=100');
if (!helpWindow) {
    this.navigateTo('help.html');
}
```